# R : choosing from 1 to 15 countries and accumulate the value if it is same or over

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement, complex-numbers, generalization

I'd like to make codes to choose countries according to the number of 1 to 15 and accumulate the value if it is same or over.

Here is what I'm doing for the cases of three countries. But I'd like to make more general one, which doesn't have to make individual codes for each number of countries.

```
select3_sum <- 0
select3_subsum <- 0
select3_compare <- 0

for (j in 1:5025){

  select_index[j,18] <- 0 
  select3 <- 0 
  for(i in 1:13){
    select3_subsum <- 0 


    for(k in i+1:14){
      select3_compare <- select_index[j,i]
      select3_subsum <- select3_compare 

      for(a in k+1:15){
        denon <- 1 

       if(select3_compare <= select_index[a,l]){
         select3_compare <- select_index[a,l]
         denon <- denon+1
         select3_subsum <- select3_subsum+select3_compare
       }
        select3_sum <- select3_sum + (select3_subsum/denon)
      }

      if(select3_compare <= select_index[j,k]){
        select3_compare <- select_index[j,k]
        denon <- denon+1
        select3_subsum <- select3_subsum+select3_compare 
      }
      else{
        select3_subsum <- select3_subsum
      }

      select3_sum <- select3_sum + (select3_subsum/denon)
    }
  }
  select3 <-(select3_sum/choose(15,3)) 
  select_index[j,18]<- select3
  select3_sum <- 0
```

data is like below. df select_index is too big to upload here so I take just small part of it.

```
structure(list(V1 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("6", 
"CHILE.index"), class = "factor"), V2 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("6", "SINGAPORE.index"), class = "factor"), 
    V3 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("7", 
    "EFTA.index"), class = "factor"), V4 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("6", "USA.index"), class = "factor"), 
    V5 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("7", 
    "ASEAN.index"), class = "factor"), V6 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("7", "INDIA.index"), class = "factor"), 
    V7 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("7", 
    "EU.index"), class = "factor"), V8 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("7", "PERU.index"), class = "factor"), 
    V9 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("7", 
    "TURKEY.index"), class = "factor"), V10 = structure(c(2L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("7", "COLOMBIA.index"
    ), class = "factor"), V11 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L), .Label = c("7", "AUSTRAILIA.index"), class = "factor"), 
    V12 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("6", 
    "CANADA.index"), class = "factor"), V13 = structure(c(2L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("7", "NEW ZEALAND.index"
    ), class = "factor"), V14 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L), .Label = c("7", "VIETNAM.index"), class = "factor"), 
    V15 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("7", 
    "CHINA.index"), class = "factor"), V16 = structure(c(2L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("0", "select1"), class = "factor"), 
    V17 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("0", 
    "select2"), class = "factor"), V18 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("0", "select3"), class = "factor"), 
    V19 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("0", 
    "select4"), class = "factor"), V20 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("0", "select5"), class = "factor"), 
    V21 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("0", 
    "select6"), class = "factor"), V22 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("0", "select7"), class = "factor"), 
    V23 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("0", 
    "selec8"), class = "factor"), V24 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("0", "selec9"), class = "factor"), 
    V25 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("0", 
    "selec10"), class = "factor"), V26 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("0", "selec11"), class = "factor"), 
    V27 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("0", 
    "selec12"), class = "factor"), V28 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("0", "selec13"), class = "factor"), 
    V29 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("0", 
    "selec14"), class = "factor"), V30 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("0", "selec15"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("V1", 
"V2", "V3", "V4", "V5", "V6", "V7", "V8", "V9", "V10", "V11", 
"V12", "V13", "V14", "V15", "V16", "V17", "V18", "V19", "V20", 
"V21", "V22", "V23", "V24", "V25", "V26", "V27", "V28", "V29", 
"V30"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

I've already got results for cases when the number of countries is one and two. the results is like below.

```
structure(list(X = 1:3, CHILE.index = c(6L, 6L, 6L), SINGAPORE.index = c(6L, 
6L, 6L), EFTA.index = c(7L, 7L, 7L), USA.index = c(6L, 6L, 6L
), ASEAN.index = c(7L, 7L, 7L), INDIA.index = c(7L, 7L, 7L), 
    EU.index = c(7L, 7L, 7L), PERU.index = c(7L, 7L, 7L), TURKEY.index = c(7L, 
    7L, 7L), COLOMBIA.index = c(7L, 7L, 7L), AUSTRAILIA.index = c(7L, 
    7L, 7L), CANADA.index = c(6L, 6L, 6L), NEW.ZEALAND.index = c(7L, 
    7L, 7L), VIETNAM.index = c(7L, 7L, 7L), CHINA.index = c(7L, 
    7L, 7L), select1 = c(6.733333333, 6.733333333, 6.733333333
    ), select2 = c(6.804603175, 6.804603175, 6.804603175), select3 = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L), select4 = c(0L, 0L, 0L), select5 = c(0L, 0L, 0L), 
    select6 = c(0L, 0L, 0L), select7 = c(0L, 0L, 0L), selec8 = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L), selec9 = c(0L, 0L, 0L), selec10 = c(0L, 0L, 0L), 
    selec11 = c(0L, 0L, 0L), selec12 = c(0L, 0L, 0L), selec13 = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L), selec14 = c(0L, 0L, 0L), selec15 = c(0L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("X", 
"CHILE.index", "SINGAPORE.index", "EFTA.index", "USA.index", 
"ASEAN.index", "INDIA.index", "EU.index", "PERU.index", "TURKEY.index", 
"COLOMBIA.index", "AUSTRAILIA.index", "CANADA.index", "NEW.ZEALAND.index", 
"VIETNAM.index", "CHINA.index", "select1", "select2", "select3", 
"select4", "select5", "select6", "select7", "selec8", "selec9", 
"selec10", "selec11", "selec12", "selec13", "selec14", "selec15"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

How can I make codes to calculate all cases(the number of countries from 1 to 15) without being too complex?

let me specify my question, if there are 15 countries, "a, b, c ... o". each countries has index value for each product from 2 to 7. and For product 1(there is no label for it, just numeric value), if we do with 3 countries, country A has 2, country B has 7 and country C has 4. the calculation process is like this. the first value would be 2. and the value of B is higher than A, so their average would be 2+7/2. but the value of C is lower than B so it would be thrown away. the number of cases according to the number of selected countries is 15 C(Combination) n The all calculation cases would be 2^15-1.

thank you for all.

Comment: Your sample code is not complete (where is `select_index` defined, final `}` missing), and at least I don't understand the question. Maybe you try to improve so that we can take a shot?

Comment: @vaettchen thank you for comment I just edited my question.

Comment: This is a riddle, not a question...   --  What is the `l` in `select_index[a,l]`?

Comment: @vaechenn I think so. l is for the third country selection. for two countries, I used j, k for. for one country, I used just j.

Comment: jung K I think I give up. The data and co e you are posting is so full of mistakes, it is impossible that you actually have tried that out yourself before posting. I'd be happy to help, even if this is beyond SO purpose, but without proper data and problem description no way. If you want to give it another try, pls make sure that what you post is a MWE, a minimum **working** example.